# Query for the execution of command with or function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is below query correct if I want to extract rows from table a and b when b.int_name is either matching with c.d_name or c.b_name or d.syn?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.n_id,
                a.dis,
                b.int_name
FROM cdb a,
     ct_int b,
     d_b c,
     d_syn d
WHERE a.dis LIKE '%hunt%' 
     && a.n_id=b.n_id 
     && b.int_name NOT LIKE 'NA' 
     && b.int_type NOT LIKE 'NA' 
     && (b.int_name NOT LIKE c.d_name
     OR b.int_name NOT LIKE c.b_name
     OR b.int_name NOT LIKE d.syn);
```

This query execution is taking hell lot of time. If I am giving above query with limit 10 or 20 it is coming in no time but without limit is getting stuck for long and don't know for that also it will give result or not. Please guide in this regard. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Check what `EXPLAIN` shows for your select query. Also provide table structure - it's hard to predict something without it.

Comment: I can see several expensive things such as Cartesian products and lots of non-indexable wildcard search (`NOT LIKE c.d_name`? Is `c.d_name` really supposed to contain wildcards?). We can't really suggest a lot if we don't know what your data looks like and what you want to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, write proper joins, without using deprecated syntax, it will allow you to see what you are doing.

You are currently joining 4 tables, with a single good join condition. The rest of the joins will perform really bad, especially since you are doing what looks like 'string not like string' joins - Normalise your data and never jon on varchar unless you really have to. Second of all, `NOT LIKE` in your case would be equivalent to `!=`. Use that.

second,

```
&& b.int_name NOT LIKE 'NA' 
&& b.int_type NOT LIKE 'NA'
```

would probably be faster written as

```
&& b.int_name != 'NA' 
&& b.int_type != 'NA'
```

third: post table structure and expected results. Maybe there is an alternative to cross joins.